# what is this assembly doing exactly?

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I have an assembly code that I am reading, and there is the following part in the code:

```
    mov    $0x28,%esi
    mov    %rax,%rdi
    callq  <strchr@plt>
    mov    %rax,%rbx
    test   %rax,%rax
    jne     somewhere
```

I am having a bit of difficulty in this code. The first move moves `0x28` to register `%esi`. The second moves `%rax` to `%rdi`, and then it does `strchr(char *rdi, char *esi)`. So, basically it returns the pointer to the first occurence after ascii `0x28`, which is `'('`. Then last test tells me that it is testing whether or not string at `rdi` has a `'('` character. If does not have, then `test %rax, %rax` will set ZeroFlags, and `jne` will not execute. Is my understanding correct?

One more question I have is when I try to check what exactly is in `%esi` after the first `mov`, I use the command `p (char *)$esi` in `gdb` but I get an output `<error: Cannot access memory at address 0x28>`. Could anyone advise me how I can view contents of `$esi`?

Comment: Yes you got it correct. `esi` holds the character itself not a pointer to it. You can do `p (char)$esi` or `p/c $esi`.

Comment: It would be more like `strchr(char *rdi, int esi)`. Also the fact `esi` is not a pointer is implicit, `esi` is only 32-bit.